# Помогите определить верные утверждения С++

Tags: c++, теория

1) Можно создать массив ссылок.

2) Указатели могут быть неинициализированными.

3) Указатели можно вычитать.

4) Указатели можно умножать на целое число.

5) Указатели можно складывать друг с другом.

6) Ссылки могут быть неинициализированными.

7) Нельзя получить адрес ссылки.

Comment: А вы попробуйте на практике :) Серьезно, то, что сам сделаешь - запомнишь надолго...

Comment: @Harry а что пробовать? Вот 5 пункт например скомпилируется и будет работать, но складывать их можно или нет по стандарту?

Comment: @pavel, если 5-й компилируется, значит нужно обновить компилятор :)

Comment: @ixSci мой borland компилирует)

Comment: @pavel, borland ещё не горит в Аду?

Comment: @ixSci у нас на 1 курсе университета только на нем и требуют, паскаль и с. На 2 курсе - c++ builder.

Comment: @Harry Поэтому и обратился, т.к. где-то ошибаюсь. Вот мои варианты: 1, 3, 7

Comment: А вообще 2,3,7 на правду похожи.

Comment: @pavel так и есть, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    // 1
    int& x1[5];

    // 2
    int * x2;

    // 3
    int *x3, *x4;
    auto dx = x3 - x4;

    // 4
    int *x5 = x3*5;

    // 5
    auto x6 = x3 + x4;

    // 6
    int& z;

    // 7
    auto y = &z;
}
```

VC++ 2015:

```
test.cpp(6): error C2234: x1: недопустимый массив ссылок
test.cpp(16): error C2296: *: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "int *"
test.cpp(19): error C2110: +: невозможно добавить два указателя
test.cpp(22): error C2530: z: ссылки должны быть инициализированы
```

[GCC](http://ideone.com/z4cJgX):

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:4:14: error: declaration of 'x1' as array of references
     int& x1[5];
              ^
prog.cpp:14:18: error: invalid operands of types 'int*' and 'int' to binary 'operator*'
     int *x5 = x3*5;
                  ^
prog.cpp:17:20: error: invalid operands of types 'int*' and 'int*' to binary 'operator+'
     auto x6 = x3 + x4;
                    ^
prog.cpp:20:10: error: 'z' declared as reference but not initialized
     int& z;
          ^
```

[Clang 3.7](http://ideone.com/ZHkpFw):

```
prog.cpp:4:12: error: 'x1' declared as array of references of type 'int &'
    int& x1[5];
           ^
prog.cpp:11:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    auto dx = x3 - x4;
    ^
prog.cpp:14:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int')
    int *x5 = x3*5;
              ~~^~
prog.cpp:17:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    auto x6 = x3 + x4;
    ^
prog.cpp:17:18: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int *')
    auto x6 = x3 + x4;
              ~~ ^ ~~
prog.cpp:20:10: error: declaration of reference variable 'z' requires an initializer
    int& z;
         ^
prog.cpp:23:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    auto y = &z;
    ^
3 warnings and 4 errors generated.
```

Comment: 7 не правильно, у Вас получается адрес переменной типа `int`, а не ссылки.

Comment: @ixSci А как ее вообще можно получить? :) *Формально* - `z` - ссылка, `&z` - адрес ссылки :) Что тут еще можно сделать?

Comment: Полагаю, что никак. Ссылка в C++ это весьма интересная сущность, она как бы есть и её как бы нет :).

Comment: @Harry поэтому я и говорил что запустить мало, надо понимать ещё что запускать) а если это понимать то можно и без запуска обойтись.

Comment: @pavel Написанное мною надо понимать, как необходимое, но отнюдь не достаточное условие...

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Можно создать массив ссылок.

Согласно стандарту C++ (8.3.4 Arrays)

> 1. ...T is called the array element type; this type shall not be a reference type, the (possibly cv-qualified) type void, a function type
>      or an abstract class type.

То есть элементами массива не могут быть ссылки, или иметь тип void (но могут быть указателями на тип Void), не могут иметь тип функций (но могут быть указателями на функции) и не могут быть объектами абстрактного класса.

> 2) Указатели могут быть неинициализированными.

Если указатель не является константным, то он может быть не инициализирован.

> 3) Указатели можно вычитать

Из стандарта C++ (5.7 Additive operators)

> 2 For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:
>
> — both operands have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type; or
>
> — **both operands are pointers to cv-qualified or cv-unqualified
>   versions of the same completely-defined object type**; or
>
> — the left operand is a pointer to a completely-defined object type
>   and the right operand has integral or unscoped enumeration type.

И там же

> 6 When two pointers to elements of the same array object are
>   subtracted, the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements.

То есть когда два указателя адресуют элементы одного массива, то их разность равна разности индексов адресуемых элементов массива.

> 4) Указатели можно умножать на целое число.

В разделе стандарта C++ "5.6 Multiplicative operators" указывается, что

> 2 The operands of * and / shall have arithmetic or unscoped
>   enumeration type;

Для указателей операция умножения не определена.

> 5) Указатели можно складывать друг с другом.

Возвращаясь к разделу стандарта C++ "5.7 Additive operators", видим, что операция сложения для указателей не определена

> 1. ...For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or unscoped 
>      enumeration type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a
>      completely-defined object type and the other shall have integral or
>      unscoped enumeration type.

Нельзя складывать указатели.

> 6) Ссылки могут быть неинициализированными.

В разделе стандарта C++ "8.3.2 References" написано, что

> 5. ... The declaration of a reference shall contain an initializer (8.5.3) 
>      except when the declaration contains an explicit extern
>      specifier (7.1.1), is a class member (9.2) declaration within a class
>      definition, or is the declaration of a parameter or a return type
>      (8.3.5); see 3.1. 7)

То есть при объявлении ссылка ссылка должна быть инициализирована за исключением тех случаев, когда она объявлена со спецификатором `extern`, является членом класса, является объявлением внутри класса или объявлением параметра функции.

> Нельзя получить адрес ссылки

Ссылки можно рассматривать как имена объектов. Когда ссылки применяется оператор взятия адреса `&`, то возвращается адрес того объекта, на который "ссылается" ссылка. Адрес самой ссылки получить нельзя, так как по крайней мере в стандарте не определено, требуют ли ссылки для себя память или нет.